# Warning from macro

Tags: c++, c, gcc, macros, g++

```
#define DF__TCDX0_RB_INFO__BRANCH_INDEX_LIST__[0, 2] 1

warning: missing whitespace after the macro name [enabled by default]
```

I was trying to compile a third party header file and gcc is throwing this warning.
I am not sure what this macro does. Is it a shortcut for defining the following ? How do I fix the warning ?

```
#define DF__TCDX0_RB_INFO__BRANCH_INDEX_LIST__0 1
#define DF__TCDX0_RB_INFO__BRANCH_INDEX_LIST__1 1
#define DF__TCDX0_RB_INFO__BRANCH_INDEX_LIST__2 1
```

Comment: It's not standard syntax, so probably some kind of compiler extension or such. Do you know which compiler the author of the library uses?

Comment: I am not sure about whether author used something special to compile. But if gcc can't recognize the macro shouldn't it throw an error instead of warning ?

Comment: It's valid code (the macro `DF__TCDX0_RB_INFO__BRANCH_INDEX_LIST__` expands to `[0, 2] 1`) so it can't be an error, but it's weird-looking (someone thought they could make a macro that takes arguments in brackets?) although I notice that with `-std=c99` the warning specifically says "ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name"... so maybe that's a difference between C89 and C99?

Comment: Do you get further errors in places where the macro is used? If not, maybe gcc's interpretation is what was intended (even though it looks strange). You could then fix the warning by adding a space before `[0, 2]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define DF__TCDX0_RB_INFO__BRANCH_INDEX_LIST__[0, 2] 1
```

In C89/C90, this is a valid macro definition, but there's nothing special about the `[` and `]` characters. It defined an object-like macro called `DF__TCDX0_RB_INFO__BRANCH_INDEX_LIST__`, and the definition is equivalent to:

```
#define DF__TCDX0_RB_INFO__BRANCH_INDEX_LIST__ [ 0 , 2] 1
```

so that any use of `DF__TCDX0_RB_INFO__BRANCH_INDEX_LIST__` expands to `[0, 2] 1`. (That's not even likely to make sense; C doesn't permit multiple index expressions within `[...]`, and `0, 2` is going to be interpreted as a comma expression equivalent to just `2`.)

C99 added a new rule (6.10.3p3):

> There shall be white-space between the identifier and the replacement list in the definition
>   of an object-like macro.

which makes the above definition invalid (a *constraint violation* requiring a diagnostic). Adding a space after the macro name:

```
#define DF__TCDX0_RB_INFO__BRANCH_INDEX_LIST__ [0, 2] 1
```

would silence the warning, but that's unlikely to be the correct fix.

It *looks* like the intent is to permit uses of the macro to use `[` and `]` for some special purpose, but that's not something the standard language supports. It *might* be a compiler-specific extension, but it's not one I've ever encountered, and I probably wouldn't recommend using it.

It might be useful to see some code that refers to the macro.